# Misunderstanding on row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I had a the following question on my Linear Algebra midterm, and from what my friend was telling me was that I am not able to do a certain row operation, which resulted in me getting a different answer, but I do not understand what row operation I am not allowed to do. The question asked to find all values of $a$ that produce, i) no solutions, ii) a unique solution and iii) infinite solutions for the matrix below.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&1\\
  1&a+2&2&5\\
  1&7&a+1&9
\end{array}
\right] $$

1. I subtracted row 3 by row 1 and row 2 by row 1

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&a+1&1&4\\
  0&6&a&8
\end{array}
\right] $$

2. Then I multiplied the second row by 6 and the third row by $a+1$

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&6(a+1)&6&24\\
  0&6(a+1)&a(a+1)&8(a+1)
\end{array}
\right] $$

3. Afterwards, I subtracted row 3 by row 2

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&6(a+1)&6&24\\
  0&0&6-a(a+1)&24-8(a+1)
\end{array}
\right] $$

4. I factored the both of the terms in the third row and multiplied the row by negative 1

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&6(a+1)&6&24\\
  0&0&(a+3)(a-2)&8(a-2)
\end{array}
\right] $$

This would suggest that for i)$a=-3$, as it would make the bottom row be three zeros equal to -40, so the system would be inconsistent iii)$a=2$, as it would make the third row a zero row, or $a=-1$ as it would make rows two and three the same row, but with different factors, which could be a zero row by subtracting multiples of one of the rows ii) Would then be $a\neq 2,-3,-1.$

However, the matrix that was used in the solution was 
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&1&1&1\\
  0&6&a&8\\
  0&0&(a+3)(a-2)&8(a-2)
\end{array}
\right] $$

with a solution of
i)$a = -3$
ii) $a \neq -3,2$
iii) $a = 2$

From my understanding it seems like they took the matrix I achieved in step one and swapped the second and third row before continuing to do all the steps I did. Why is this the correct way to reduce the matrix to REF, and what row operation was I prohibited from doing that lead me to my answer opposed to this one?

Comment: When I substitute $a=-1$ in the first matrix in step 4$, I get that the third row is the negative of the first, so there is no inconsistency.  I don't see any mistake in your work other than that.

Comment: When you multiply a row by $a+1$, you are only performing a valid row operation if $a+1\neq0$.

Comment: Thanks! I that is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying a row by $a+1$ but first ensure if $a+1=0$ so $a=-1$ also. Rest your proof is correct